# ViewModel is passing null values to controller on submit

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

My view :

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("", "", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "responseEntryForm" }))
{

    <div id="SiteDeployment" class="tabcontent">
        @Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Sections,Model.Sections)
        @for (int index = 0; index < Model.Sections.Count; index++)
        {
            <fieldset class="leftFieldset">
                <div class="inputFieldDiv">
                    <label class="GroupHeadings"> @Model.Sections[index].Name</label><br />

                    @for (int subIndex = 0; subIndex < Model.Sections[index].SubSections.Count; subIndex++)
                    {
                        <div style="width:100%">
                            <div class="SubGroups">
                                @Model.Sections[index].SubSections[subIndex].Name
                            </div>
                            <div class="subEntries">
                                @for (int subsubIndex = 0; subsubIndex < Model.Sections[index].SubSections[subIndex].QuestionsList.Count; subsubIndex++)
                                {
                                    <div class="subSections">
                                        <label class="StrucQuestions"> @Model.Sections[index].SubSections[subIndex].QuestionsList[subsubIndex].Question</label>
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.Sections[index].SubSections[subIndex].QuestionsList[subsubIndex].Response, new SelectList(Model.ResponseList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "strucType", @id = "ddl_" + subIndex + Model.Sections[index].SubSections[subIndex].QuestionsList[subsubIndex].QuestionID })

                                    </div>
                                }
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
                </div>
            </fieldset>
        }
```

calling my controller and passing form data as below using ajax call:

```
function submitResponses() {

   $.ajax({
       url: '@Url.Action("SaveResponsesData", "Dashboard")',
       datatype: 'json',
        type: "POST",
        data: $('#responseEntryForm').serialize(),
        success: function (result) {
            if (result == "T ") {
                alert("Save is successful");
            }


        }


    });

}
```

and my controller is like below:

```
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveResponsesData(ResponseEntryViewModel objResponseEntryViewModel)
    {
        // ViewBag.SelectedType = TypeValue.ToUpper();

            return View();


    }
```

My ViewModel looks like below:

```
public class ResponseEntryViewModel
{
    public int TypeID { get; set; }
    public string TypeName { get; set; }
    public string CompletedBy { get; set; }
    public string CompletedOn { get; set; }
    public int User_ID { get; set; }
    public List<SectionDataModel> Sections = new List<SectionDataModel>();
    public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> ResponseList { get; set; }


    public class SectionDataModel
    {
        public int SectionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int TypeId { get; set; }
         public List<SubSectionModel> SubSections = new List<SubSectionModel>();

    }

    public class SubSectionModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public int SectionId { get; set; }
        public List<QuestionModel> QuestionsList = new List<QuestionModel>();

    }

    public class QuestionModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public string Question { get; set; }
        public bool Response { get; set; }

    }
}
```

In my view model ResponseEntryViewModel , i have a list of sections which has a list of sub sections which further has a list of questions and user is entering responses to those questions from my view.

When I click on submit. My viewModel is not having any values and Sections count is 0.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure that you are calling `SaveResponsesData` in your controller? Because you didn't specify the controller and action names here `@using (Html.BeginForm("", ""`

Comment: Yes @S.Akbari, just edited my question. I using an ajax call to pass my form data to controller.

Comment: Your code (as presented here) will not stop the form from submitting, and since you have the `@using` as @S.Akbari mentions, it will submit to the action you're on.

Comment: Correct @HereticMonkey and I've used it many times and it works perfectly. But I am not able to figure out why in this scenario my viewmodel is not taking any values on submit.

Comment: Please show the code for ResponseEntryViewModel also

Comment: I've updated my question with view model @DanielStackenland

Comment: I'm not sure, but it could be that you initialize you lists Sections = new List<SectionDataModel>(); Maybe it clears the posted data?

Comment: It sure is a complicated viewmodel, how does your posted data look? It's probably the modelbinding that fails, I think you should consider make a separate model for the response posting that is flattend.

Comment: @DanielStackenland: But my requirement is such where I need nested lists and then finally have to save responses to questionnaire that belongs to sub sections which belongs to sections.

Comment: Sure, but I guess you only need the ids of the section & subsection when saving the response?

Comment: Correct @DanielStackenland. Could you help me with a sample of ViewModel that you're suggesting.

Comment: Have you tried using fiddler to see exactly what is going to your server, i found that sometimes for some reason if the index where messed up or not passed it would not bind.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the issue but it could be.

```
datatype
```

should be

```
dataType
```

Comment: Try removing that line entirely. Also, where is the button that calls the javascript function?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest would be just to remove `dataType` attribute completely. You are sending form-encoded data, not JSON there.

If you want to send JSON to server, you would have to use [FromBody] attribute:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult SaveResponsesData([FromBody] ResponseEntryViewModel objResponseEntryViewModel)
{
    // ...
    return View();
}
```

However, you don't have data in JSON format. For JSON, normally you use JavaScript object and call `JSON.stringify(data)` function on it. `JQuery`'s `serialize()` uses different format, for form-posting - *Encode a set of form elements as a string for submission.*

Example of this formatting would be: `single=Single&multiple=Multiple&multiple=Multiple3&check=check2&radio=radio1`

You might also have to set `contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"`

Comment: Tried it and replace my ajax call as below but still not working.
  $.ajax({
           url: '@Url.Action("SaveResponsesData", "Dashboard")',
           contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
           type: 'post',
           data: test,
            success: function (result) {
                if (result == "T ") {
                    alert("Save is successful");
                }
                

            }


        });

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be a lot easier if you make a separete model for saving the response, something like, I hope you understand what I trying to show:

```
public class SaveResponseModel
    {
        public int SubSectionID { get; set; }
        public int QuestionID { get; set; }
        public bool Response { get; set; }
    }


[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult SaveResponsesData(List<SaveResponseModel> responses)
    {
        // ViewBag.SelectedType = TypeValue.ToUpper();
        return View();
    }
```

.cshtml:

```
for each Sections, SubSection, Question...{
            <input name="responses.Index" type="hidden" value="@item.QuestionID" />
            <input name="responses[@item.QuestionID].QuestionID" type="hidden" value="@item.QuestionID" />
            <input name="responses[@item.QuestionID].SubSectionID" type="hidden" value="@item.SubSectionID" />
            @Html.DropDownList((string)string.Format("responses[{0}].Response", @item.QuestionID), new SelectList(Model.ResponseList, "Value", "Text"), new { @class = "strucType", @id = "ddl_" + subIndex + Model.Sections[index].SubSections[subIndex].QuestionsList[subsubIndex].QuestionID })
```

}

Comment: But we can use only one viewmodel in a view , right? So if i use this VM then how do I bind my controls?

Comment: Keep you model for rendering the view and use this for saving.

Comment: But how do i use two viewmodels in a single view?

Comment: You dont "use" SaveResponseModel in the view it´s just a class used for parsing the response

Comment: I don't think I am able to understand you approach @Daniel

Comment: Ok, too bad, but it's not that complicated...you just dont use the same viewmodel in your post-action as in your razor-view. Hope you solve you problem someway...